# How to remove modules not used in quilljs

Tags: performance, module, size, quill

We are using Quill for basic formatting (Bold, Italic, Link, BlockQuote). However Quill.min.js is the largest file that we've in our page.

We are looking to cut the size of the file by including the necessary modules only (for e.g. remove Syntax and Formula).

What is the way to get them removed? Do we need to setup the environment as described in Development page? Would it be possible to comment or remove the codes in quill.js? Appreciate any guidance

Comment: Being that the quill.min.js file is under 200 KiB uncompressed it really shouldn't be a problem for you. If your web server is using gzip to compress its payload the actual data transmitted will be around 20KiB. Which will then be cached on the client anyway. What is the reason for wanting to make the script smaller?

Answer (score 2):

You can use quill.core.js and quill.core.css instead which will not have extra modules like Syntax and Formula. These files are not minified for you however. If you want to customize further then you will have to build Quill yourself.